# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax near ''

Tags: mysql, sql

I copied a generated stored procedure.

Upon re-running it I get You have an error in your SQL syntax near '' at line 11.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `usp_TEST`()
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT 'Returns the total number of available vehicles'
BEGIN
    SELECT  COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM    FLEET
    WHERE RENTED = 0
    AND     InService = 1;
END
```

Adding delimiter // and ending with delimiter; was of no help. No errors but also the stored procedure does not get created.
Any and all help welcome......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already guessed, in order for your MySQL *client* not to interpret the `;` that terminates the `SELECT` statement as the end of the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement, you must inform it that you wish to use some other statement delimiter.

In the [`mysql`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) command-line client, you can do this with the `DELIMITER` [command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-commands.html).  For example, to change your statement delimiter to a double forward-slash:

```
DELIMITER //
```

If using some other client software, you will have to check its documentation to discover the appropriate method of changing statement delimiter.

Once done, you can then do:

```
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'%' PROCEDURE usp_TEST()
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT 'Returns the total number of available vehicles'
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM   FLEET
    WHERE  RENTED = 0
    AND    InService = 1;
END//
```

However, because in this case your procedure only contains one statement, you don't need to use a [`BEGIN ... END` compound statement block](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/begin-end.html) and could therefore avoid changing delimiters altogether:

```
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'%' PROCEDURE usp_TEST()
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT 'Returns the total number of available vehicles'
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM   FLEET
WHERE  RENTED = 0
AND    InService = 1;
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply eggyal. I'm using HeidiSQL client.
Indeed I've tried without success: 
DELIMITER //
  MyCODE
DELIMITER ;

Turns out for my case it ONLY works when adding DELIMITER // at the beginning ONLY.
I've found my answer on the following site: [link](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MySQL/Q_27383525.html)

Thanks to all for the help

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html says:

> If a user value is given for the DEFINER clause, it should be a MySQL account specified as 'user_name'@'host_name' (the same format used in the GRANT statement)

In other words, you need to quote the user and hostname. Treat them as string literals:

```
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'%' PROCEDURE usp_TEST()
. . .
```

Comment: Actually, if one inspects the [source of the OP's post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6845a858-bd5d-42c4-af4a-1dd54cecb656/view-source), the user specification *was* appropriately quoted.  I missed that when copy-pasting into my answer, though.

Comment: @eggyal: Those are back-ticks, not single-quotes.

Comment: See [Specifying Account Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/account-names.html): "*Quote user names and host names as identifiers or as strings, using either backticks (“`\``”), single quotation marks (“`'`”), or double quotation marks (“`"`”).*"

Comment: Besides which, were this the problem, the error would not have been "near '' on line 11".

Comment: Aha! Thank you, I didn't know user names and host names could be quoted as identifiers.